# spring data and mongodb with @Query annotation for an array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have the class:

```
public class Game {

@Id
private Integer gameId;

private int prize;
private int[] numbers;

//gets and sets

}
```

then I have the mongorepository class:

```
public interface GameRepository extends MongoRepository<Game, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "{ 'numbers' : {$all : [?0] }}")
    public List<JogoLotoFacil> myFind(int[] numbers);

}
```

When I execute the query straight onto mongodb I get the results that I want, but running on java with spring data I always get an empty list.

If I run findAll() I get the correst list.

Question is: is it possible to use @Query for arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The custome **[`@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based)** annotation is buggy for some operators. Would suggest to create your own custom interface and your implementation class to execute the custom query using the MongoTemplate. For example, create an interface with a name that appends Custom:

```
public interface GameRepositoryCustom {
    public List<JogoLotoFacil> myFind(int[] numbers); 
}
```

Modify the `GameRepository` and add the `GameRepositoryCustom` interface to be extended:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends GameRepositoryCustom, MongoRepository {

}
```

Create your implementation class to implement the methods defined in `GameRepositoryCustom` interface.

```
public class GameRepositoryImpl implements GameRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<JogoLotoFacil> myFind(int[] numbers) {
        return mongoTemplate.find(
            Query.query(Criteria.where("numbers").all(numbers)), Game.class);
    }
}
```